# CentOs, Apache24

Tags: centos, apache-2.4, centos6

Essentially I am installing apache2.4 onto centOs6.6 using the Apache2 CHEF cookbook.  I have it working to the point where all the service commands work minus the

```
 sudo service httpd24-httpd graceful
```

command, unfortunately the chef script will not complete without that service.  It provides me with the following error:

```
/opt/rh/httpd24/root/usr/sbin/apachectl: line 112: /usr/bin/systemctl: No such file or directory
```

sure enough that file (systemctl) isn't there.  The cookbook is just deferring to yum to install apache - so I am a bit confused as to why it isn't installed, IF it is needed.  How is systemctl installed on centos?

Folow up question: Isn't systemctl an ubuntu app?  If is my apache24 install messed up OR does apache24 have a reliance on this?

---

So I retried on a fresh VM

```
 cd /yum/repos.d
 wget http://repos.fedorapeople.org/repos/jkaluza/httpd24/epel-httpd24.repo
sudo yum install httpd24
sudo service httpd24-httpd graceful
```

Then a

```
/opt/rh/httpd24/root/usr/sbin/apachectl: line 116: /usr/bin/systemctl: No such file or directory
```

It doesn't look to be associated with the cookbook at all.  It looks tobe completely associated with the httpd24 install

Comment: Looks like you have cookbook, written for Centos 7. systemctl doesn't present in Centos 6

Comment: I am not sure it is the cookbok though.  Isn't apachectl installed by httd24?  If so wouldn't that be a bug in the apache instal?  If it is in the cookbook it should be easier to fix...

Comment: It looks like httpd24 to me...

Comment: So http://repos.fedorapeople.org/repos/jkaluza/httpd24/epel-httpd24.repo has another version of httpd24. with systemctl use in init script. I'll try to reproduce your issue on my environment

Comment: Is that not the repo to use?  I am really not a devops or even ops guy - I am trying to plug a hole for a couple of weeks...  And this is keping my engineers from deploying, so it has become my priority. And thank you for your assistance

Comment: I reproduced it. Don't use "graceful" command for it. 

Try to use sudo service httpd24-httpd start

or sudo service httpd24-httpd restart

Comment: Yes - it looks like the apache2 cookbook for chef in circulation uses "graceful" internally.   I will chase down with them.  I was really hoping there was something I could do on the linux side to work around this.  In your opinion is there somewhere I should be reporting this issue?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38690/discussion-between-anton-makovetsky-and-akaphenom).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a some bug. I reproduced your steps and received the same. With this package you can use all commands except "graceful". so try

```
sudo service httpd24-httpd restart or
sudo service httpd24-httpd reload
```

instead of sudo service httpd24-httpd graceful

Answer (score 0):

The new init system on CentOS 7 is systemd. You control that with systemctl.

Comment: I am on centOs 6, it looks as though the httpd24 - particualrtly th egraceful command isn't working on centOs 6.  If you  peak at my update, you can see my experiment.